# Unexpected high 503 error rate on "youtubeAnalytics.reports.query" API

Tags: youtube-api

Today, November 9th 2016, we've noticed an high 503 error rate on the "youtubeAnalytics.reports.query" API since few hours.

About the 15% of requests is currently failing with an 503 error (see attached screenshot from the Google APIs Console).

Is anyone of you aware of any issue on the YouTube side?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A **503** error might result during heavy load or for larger more complex requests. For larger requests consider requesting data for a shorter time period. Also consider implementing [exponential backoff](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/coreErrors#backoff). The frequency of these errors can be dependent on the view and the amount of reporting data assiciated with that view. A query that casues a 503 error for one view will not necessarily cause an error for the same query with a different view.

Here's a related SO ticket which encountered 503 error: [503 Service Unavailable when threading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14486820/503-service-unavailable-when-threading)

Answer (score 0):

It looks it was a temporary issue on the YouTube side. Few hours after everything got back to normal.